# Accuracy of key points for moving subjects

Tags: photogrammetry

I am currently working on a project where I have a fast-moving subject (a tree) which I capture from multiple angles using multiple cameras. My intention is to use photogrammetry to create a 3D model of the tree.

Apart from the image processing that I need to do, a big concern of mine is synchronizing the cameras. Why? Because if one camera triggers later than the others, the tree's crown will have moved. Suppose I use a branch of that tree as a key point in the images and the branch has moved between the frames of 2 different cameras, I assume that the spatial accuracy of that key point will be worse. The question is though by how much?

I know the expected wind speed and can thus roughly guess the maximum speed at which I expect the branches to move. If I am able to predict how that would affect the spatial accuracy of the key points and thus the resulting point cloud/mesh, I could estimate how much of a synchronization error I can allow myself in order to fulfill the requirements for the spatial accuracy of the model.

My approach to doing this prediction would be to apply the laws of error propagation to the collinearity equations. However, my fear is that this approach is too simple: Such an error could also manifest itself in wrongly aligned images and thus cause errors in the extrinsic image calibration.

I obviously searched Google Scholar for papers that go in that direction, but so far have been unable to find something that answers those questions. In the long term, my plan is to create a small scale experiment on a small tree to determine those limits experimentally, but in the meanwhile, I want to ask 2 things:

1. Has any research been conducted that goes into that direction?
2. Are my thoughts correct or am I going in the completely wrong direction?

As always, if there's anything wrong or confusing about my question or you need more info, please drop me a comment and I will edit the question accordingly.